# Fitting data to a distribution that appears lognormal without right-hump

Tags: fitting, discrete-data, scipy, statsmodels

I will like to fit a distribution and extract its moments in Python, given Length of Stay (LOS) data in hospitals.

Asking out of curiosity, suppose the plot of the data looks like:

[image: Oiginal image taken from https://pythonhealthcare.org/category/simpy-clinical-pathway-simulation/ before edit of right hump]

The reason why I made the plot look like that is due to the fact that where I reside in, there are a surprisingly high number of people having long stay (>30 days) in hospitals.

Are there standard procedures that I should proceed with (e.g. scaling) before attempting to fit the data to known-distributions in SciPy?

Or is there actually a distribution out there which is not in SciPy's built-in distributions?

Some insight will be deeply appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You may want to take a look at [tag:mixture]s and [tag:finite-mixture-model]s.

Comment: @StephanKolassa Thanks for the suggestion! I'll look into it :)

Comment: Would it be useful in your work to separately model these two groups, and then sum the models?

Comment: @JamesPhillips I did think of that after looking at mixtures and finite-mixture models as suggested by Stephan but am unable to find evidence online that simply summing the models is a statistically correct approach.